# How to have flexible Data Entry form of 150 columns in ASP.NET ? Perhaps DevExpress or other thirdparty Tools?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I am encountering a situation such as, I want to offer a data entry form of almost more than 100 fields of certain Database Table. It was an old database of Invoice of a particular company and cannot be altered.

So, I would have obviously a resultant Data Grid  ( Probably HTML Table ) or MVC Grid containing user entered data inside. But the problem is How to Offer 120 fields in an entry form? ( Could be a partial View contained inside JQuery )? This comes an idea about inline editable Grid. Would that be better? Or DevExpress offers such controls? Would Spreadsheet be helpfull?

or any other technique would be helpfull to adopt for this?
Any body having any idea?

Regards
Usman

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining what those 100+ fields could be. Are you sure it's not simpler: 4 or 5 fields for a quantity of an item repeated for many items?

Comment: no no...actually it"s the same what I talked..
There are few calculated values from some other fields and rest are normal
but not necassary that all fields are manadatory...

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make it any clearer. What is it an invoice for?

Comment: Data related with Logistics, where there are 3 stakholders participating..Forwarder, Client and the company which reduces the cost for it's clients..

So in past the data is being structured in that way, like more than 100 columns were introduced in single table. and this all data entry needs to be done by somebody else and the application needs to be on the cloud. That's the reason , we I need to have such data entry form.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I don't think a Grid would be a good way: that would just be too wide. I think the best way would be a series of Tabs each of which contains the data pertaining to one logical section of the invoice (e.g. a section for Forwarder, another for Client, etc etc).

As a design note, try to group items into sections small enough that the user doesn't need to scroll. Everything is a section should be visible of a normal sized screen. This makes it easier for the user.

Comment: hmm...Good.I would see first whether it would be nice in this case,
What about DevExpress Spreadsheet solution?
like Excel Spreadsheet? I have paid license of DevExpress.

Comment: DevExpress probably has a TabControl, but I don't think a Spreadsheet would be a good interface (although I might be wrong!)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is possible in your case but since you mentioned

> any other technique would be helpfull

This is what I can suggest: In Visual Studio (download free copy here http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx), in your MVC project:

1. Add Entity Framework package from nuget if you don't already have it (Install-Package EntityFramework from Package Manager console in VS)
2. Add an EF model in VS by dragging you database table to model designer
3. Add an Entity Framework controller with Read/Write Actions

This will create views in your project where a user can go an CRUD the table rows. And will also ensure basic constraint checking.

Check this tutorial for Entity Framework details: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application